# What is the meaning of bother exercising?

Tags: meaning

I never saw **verb+ing** after word **bother**.

> Not surprising, since I've been way too busy cooking fattening food to
>   **bother exercising**

What is the meaning of bother exercising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bother doing something is to decide something is important enough to do and to make a real effort to do it. If it bothers you to do something, that means you might not enjoy doing it and may view it as an unpleasant chore.

In this case, the person is saying he or she is cooking a lot of fattening food (***way too busy*** implies doing too much of something). The person is saying exercising is not worthwhile, because he or she has a poor diet and exercise won't make him/her healthy. Ironically, exercise is probably **more** important if you eat poorly, not less.